# image maximum file size based on image dimension

Tags: image, size

I wanted my server to receive image from user based on image dimensions , but i'm not sure how to determine the maximum image file size based on image dimensions . I don't want the user to upload a malicious image with unreasonable file size but i also don't want to miscalculate the maximum file size and wrongly denying the user upload for being "too big" in file size.

For example the user upload an image with dimension width size 720 and height size 480 , what will be the maximum possible file size for that image ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a programming question but digital image processing.

Answer (score 2):

You can derive your limit based on

> (number of pixels) x (number of bytes needed to represent a pixel)

Your maximum number of pixels is set at 720 x 480.
Based on an article about [Color depth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_depth), the maximum number of bytes per pixel in use is 8 bytes(64-bit).

This gives you a limit of 8 x 720 x 480 = **2 764 800 bytes**.

But typically, you can expect smaller image sizes, due to:

- color depth of the image being less than 64-bit
- images uploaded in a format which uses some compression(e.g. PNG) instead of raw data

If the calculated limit is too high, you can use this [calculator](https://www.scantips.com/basics1d.html#four) to see the expected image sizes for different formats, so you can choose a limit that better suits you.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

Honestly speaking, I wouldn't be looking at the maximum possible size. I would rather be aiming for the most common file size given a specific frame size. And this will hugely depend on other attributes that make an image what it is, the **Bit** size.

I would advise you to bet on **24 Bit** size, which is common for most digital photos used today. Obviously, there're photos with Bits up to **64 Bit** but I can assure you that you won't find many downloaded from the internet. A 64 Bit on that size would yield a 2.64MB size and that's too big for our day to day storage of images to our clouds. Unless you're aiming or HD photos obviously.

But Here's my proposal, using the most common **24 Bit**.

First we need to remember that each pixel(square) on a photo holds a byte for each of the 3 o makeup colors namely; `red`, `green`, `blue`. So each pixel equals to `3 bytes`, with each color equaling to 1byte, where `1 byte == 8bits`. But there's no need to convert them into bits since we are interested in `byte` size. Commonly, our digital images are 24 bits per pixel, and that works out to the `3 bytes` i had described earlier.

In your case, a max-frame size of `720px` x `480px` result in a total pixels of:

`totalPixels = 720 x 480 = 345,600 pixels`;

So far we know that each pixel holds 3 bytes for the assumed **24 Bit Depth size**, so we can calculate the total bytes:

`totalBytes = 345600 x 3 =  1, 036, 800 bytes` ... So our image size is now given in bytes.

Let's convert it to **megabytes**:

`totalBytesInMB = 1036800 / (1024 x 1024) = 0.989mb` ... Equivalent to `1MB`

This is also equivalent to (in kb):

`totalBytesInKB = 1036800 / (1024) = 1,012.5 kb` ...

A maximum size of about `1MB` or `1.1MB` would be sufficient as max. Do you really want to store images over 2MB? that's already going to affect download and upload performance on your app.